Termux: Permission Denied Creating Directory (gpg Key)"
I'm having trouble updating packages in Termux due to a permission error when trying to create a directory for the GPG key.

Attempting to search for packages with pkg search jed results in an error message about missing GPG key.

When trying to create the directory for the GPG key using mkdir -p /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/keyrings/, I receive a "Permission denied" error.

Running termux-setup-storage to grant storage permissions also fails.


Hope someone can help me resolve these issues.
